# Postgresql : Alternative to joining the same table multiple times

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, database-table

If i have two tables **entry** and **entry_metadata**, with the entry_metadata as a description table for the entry referenced by entry_id and a variable.

If i have this :

**entry**

```
id | name   |
-------------
1  | entry1 |
2  | entry2 |
3  | entry3 |
```

**entry_metadata**

```
id | entry_id | variable | value
1  |    1     | width    | 10
2  |    1     | height   | 5
3  |    2     | width    | 8
4  |    2     | height   | 7
5  |   ...    |  ....    | ..
```

and i'm getting the table :

```
id | name   | width | height| ...  | ...
-----------------------------------------
1  | entry1 |  10   |  5    |
2  | entry2 |  8    |  7    |
3  | entry3 |  ..   |  ..   |
```

by the sql :

```
select e.name, em.width, emr.height
from
  public.entry e
left join
  public.entry_metadata em
on
  em.entry_id = e.id and em.variable = 'width'
left join
  public.entry_metadata emr
on
  emr.entry_id = e.id and emr.variable = 'height'
```

The query above works. But as I add more variables to get the values (the entry_metadata table includes a large variety of variables) from the entry metadata. The query gets really really slow. every join I do slows down the execution greatly. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select id, name,
       max(case when variable = 'width' then value end) as width,
       max(case when variable = 'height' then value end) as height
from public.entry_metadata em
group by id, name;
```

Adding additional columns is just adding more aggregation functions.

Comment: would this be faster than the join alternative?

Comment: @muffin . . . You need to try it on your data and your system.  WIth lots of columns, it is likely to be faster, but there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Just use subselects for this:

```
SELECT
  e.id,
  e.name,
  (SELECT em.value FROM public.entry_metadata em WHERE em.entry_id = e.id AND em.variable = 'width') AS width,
  (SELECT em.value FROM public.entry_metadata em WHERE em.entry_id = e.id AND em.variable = 'height') AS height
FROM
  public.entry e
```

So for each new variable you just need to add one more subselect.

Comment: i've tested it but it's a lot slower than the join

Comment: Do you have indexed your tables? Maybe missing index on entry_metadata.entry_id?

Comment: yeah.. it's actually good if it's 2 joins.. but if i'm getting 3 to 4.. the performance toll is exponential..

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to get around this?

Yes, replace `entry_metadata` table with addtional column in `entry` (possible solutions are `hstore` or `jsonb`) with key - value storage of entry metadata.

Btw. your tables represents well known controversial database desing pattern known as "Entity Attribute Value".